# AccessControlException in Applet

Tags: java, applet

This applet runs fine in eclipse viewer. I cannot run it from any browser. How can I resolve this issue? I get this error from my java applet console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.awt.AWTPermission watchMousePointer)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(Unknown Source)
 at nopulse.update(nopulse.java:448)
 at nopulse.paint(nopulse.java:316)
 at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Applets running in a browser use a Security Manager.  There are many things that applets in a browser are not allowed to do.  If you insist that your applets do these things,  deploy your applet as a [signed applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html)

Comment: And explain to the user why it is necessary to OK a signed applet.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your policy files accordingly. See [this](http://www.cyberspaceview.com/kev/data/nerding/coding/Java%20policy%20notes%5Eby%20Kev.htm) on how to do it.

Comment: Policy files are not useful at time of deployment, so why bother with them at all?