# My jar file is signed but I still get a security exception

Tags: java, permissions, jogl

I've signed my jar file with a key I've created, but whenever I try to run my app i get the error:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "createRobot")

This error arises even after I agree to allow the application to run.

The application is a simple applet using JOGL and JBullet. You can find it here: **http://kevservices.com/jogl.php**

I'm using the robot to keep the mouse centered as much as possible and remain within the bounds of the application. I've searched for solutions and have tried what I've found; To no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AccessControlException in Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446524/accesscontrolexception-in-applet)

Comment: Could you Please elaborate? My jar file is signed and the link you provided had no explanation; other than editing policy files.